# Not too sure how to move on from here. Using linked list to search?

Tags: c++, nodes

Question: Create a Linked list of nodes. Each node should have student names, age, course num, grades and pointer that is used to link the next node in the list. Use append node member function to generate a linked list of 5 students. Create a search member function to display the name of the student who has got 'A' grade. Assume that only one student got "A" grade.

Not too sure how to move on from here. I am new to linked list/nodes and not too sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  string name;
  int age;
  int coursenum;
  char grade;
  node *next;
};

node *search (node * head)
{
  node *temp = head;
  char grade;
  while (temp != NULL)
    {
      //if (temp->grade == 'A')
      //if((temp->grade, grade)=='A')
      if(strcmp(temp->grade, grade)=='A')
    {
      cout << temp->name;
      return temp;
    }
      temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main ()
{
  node *head = NULL;

  string name;
  int age;
  int coursenum;
  char grade;

  int i = 0;

  while (i < 2)
    {
      cout << "Enter the students name: ";
      cin >> name;
      cout << "Enter the studens age: ";
      cin >> age;
      cout << "Enter the students course number: ";
      cin >> coursenum;
      cout << "Enter the students grade: ";
      cin >> grade;
      node *temp = new node;
      temp->grade = grade;
      temp->next = head;
      head = temp;
      i++;
    }
  search (head);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement in search function must be;

```
if (temp->grade == 'A')
```

However, your problem is not in your understanding of linked list. You cannot write values to name, age, and coursenum correctly. You need to assign all your read values to struct's variables.

```
temp->name = name;
temp->age = age;
temp->coursenum = coursenum;
temp->grade = grade;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strcmp(string1,string2) // returns 0 if strings are equal.
    String str1 = 'apple';
    String str2 = 'apple';
    if(strcmp(str1,str2))
    {
     cout<<"inside if";
    }
    else{
    cout<<"inside else"
    }
```

// output will be "inside else"
because if condition will evaluate to '0'